# HTML <audio> with mp3 stored on OneDrive

Tags: audio, html, mp3, onedrive

I'm trying to figure out a way of storing mp3. files on OneDrive and using HTML `<audio>` tags to play them on a website. I want to mention that it's a small site and I'm doing this just to help (not for money). There are other things I don't know as to how this would practically work (other limitations etc.), but first here's some more initial information:

There is a site that has multiple .mp3 files, stored on the same server, that are played via HTML `<audio>` tags. I know there might be better ways of playing audio on a website, but for what's needed, it works really well.

Because the site owner is expecting increased traffic, I am trying to figure out a way of reducing the server load by hosting the mp3 files somewhere else. I've looked into other options, but for now, the owner wants to keep the look and functionality identical and doesn't want to embed the files hosted on a third party dedicated website, i.e. SoundCloud or some other website for podcasts etc.

Seeing as the owner already has a Microsoft 365 subscription (former Office 365 - don't get me started on the name change), I thought of using OneDrive as a solution. However, as you might already know, OneDrive doesn't provide direct file links, but `https://1drv.ms/...` links, which take you to the OneDrive page.

While doing some research on this topic, I found a few possible solutions:

1. Replace `.ms` with `.ws`, so now it's `https://1drv.ws/...`
   While it seems to work, the problem is I don't know exactly what that does in the background so I don't know what implications in regards to possible security or privacy issues could appear down the line, especially seeing as simply navigating to https://1drv.ws/ under more info it shows a GitHub page with Chinese text.
2. Get the embed code from OneDrive and use the resid and authkey to replace them in this link `http://storage.live.com/items/{resid}?authkey={authkey}`
   This feels like it's downloading the entire file before starting to play. I had a 30+ minute file at 128kbps, so about 30 MB and it took a long while to start playing.
3. I found another suggestion of again, using the details in the embed code `https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=...&resid=...&authkey=...` and replacing the word `embed` with `download`, so it's now `https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=...&resid=...&authkey=...`
   This seems to work the same as option 1, but it's using the official site.

Another thing I don't know is related to possible practical limitations of OneDrive i.e. does it have a bandwidth limitation in regards to shared files (number of downloads or total size)?
I found a [question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onedrive-shared-file-download-limit/9a582223-4359-44a0-b5be-4057fdb1e574) that touches on this topic, but the official MS answer was to ask specifically in OneDrive, so there might be a limitation but it looks like they'd rather not state it so publicly.

I'm sure there are many things I'm missing here so any input is appreciated, either in regards to this specific OneDrive way of doing it, or even other ways that might be better in the long run.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now at least, it seems the best way of doing this is option 3, using the link in the embed code `https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=...&resid=...&authkey=...` and replacing the word `embed` with `download`, so it's now `https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=...&resid=...&authkey=...`

There are minor delays when first loading the site and when clicking play for any file, as opposed to when the files were directly hosted on the same server, but that's to be expected and doesn't affect the overall usability.

Also, in regards to OneDrive bandwidth limits, I asked and got a reply - normally there isn't a bandwidth limit for shared files (number of downloads or total download size/day or account etc.), however, there generally is a theoretical limit for file uploads (number of files/24h), but everything can be subject to change on a per account basis, so your mileage may vary.